# How to compare pointers of two custom types in go

Tags: go

I am trying to write some code that needs to compare the configuration of two Azure SQL Servers and Databases.

The Type data can be found here:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/sql/armsql#Server
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/sql/armsql#Database

The objects consists of a number of pointers to custom type values that may or may not be set.
Unset values are `nil` and set values eventually resolve down to Strings, Ints or Bools.

In python i would walk the object and comparing all the values with just a few lines of looped code. But in go, this dose not seem to be possible or "correct".

My first attempt was go:

```golang
if serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login != serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login {
        log.Log.Info("Login Does Not Match", "serverA", serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login, "serverB", serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login)
}
```

But this fails even when the two are identical.
`Login Does Not Match    {"serverA": "My-Admin", "serverB": "My-Admin"}`
My understanding is what i actually did here was compare the pointer addresses.

I then added * to compare the actual values, this worked better until i tested with `Login` not being set on ServerA, which results in:

```golang
if *serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login != *serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login {
        log.Log.Info("Login Does Not Match", "serverA", serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login, "serverB", serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login)
}
```

`Observed a panic in reconciler: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

The final solution that "works" but less then ideal doing this over 50+ properties:

```golang
    if serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login == nil && serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login == nil {
        log.Log.Info("Login is nil in both")
    } else if serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login == nil {
        log.Log.Info("Login is nil in serverA")
    } else if serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login == nil {
        log.Log.Info("Login is nil in serverB")
    } else if *serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login != *serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login {
        log.Log.Info("Login Does Not Match", "serverA", serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login, "serverB", serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login)
    } else {
        log.Log.Info("Login Matches", "serverA", serverA.Properties.Administrators.Login, "serverB", serverB.Properties.Administrators.Login)
    }
```

Does anyone know of a more elegant way of doing this in go?